# Android Web view do not Display loaded Html content on some phone specifically htc one x

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-webview

I'm loading some Html content with CSS in a WebView.
Everything works fine on every phone, but the HTC one x (android version 4.1.1 ).
Nothing gets displayed in the WebView on this phone.
Below is my code snippet.

The function which gives me the formatted WebView Content:

```
public String getFormattedWebViewContents(String content)
{       

    String htmlString = "ul{" +
                "padding-left: 10px;" +
                "padding-bottom:7px;" +
                "color:#818181;" +
                "font-size: 10px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }" +
                "ul .bdr { line-height: 16px;}" + 
                ".flt-lt{float:left;}"   + 
                ".flt-rt{float:right;}"  +
                "ul li{padding:10px 5px 10px 10px !important;}"+
                "ul li h4 {height: 25px; border: 1px solid #DEDEDE; font-family:Calibri;font-size:18px;" + 
                "margin-bottom:10px !important;font-weight:bold;text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;margin-left: -7px;" +
                "margin-right: 0px !important;" +
                "color: #7CA834;" +
                "font-family: Calibri;" +
                "font-size: 18px;" +
                "font-weight: bold;" +
                "height: 25px;" +
                "margin-bottom: 1px;" +
                "padding-left: 10px;" +
                "padding-top: 10px !important;" +
                "text-align: left;"+
                "vertical-align: middle;"+                  
                "background-color: #F2F2F2;color: #7CA834;}"+
                ".bdr1 .sml-font{font-size:11px !important;padding-top:3px ;color: #7CA834 !important;font-family: Arial !important;font-weight: bold !important;}"+
                "ul{margin-bottom:14px; margin-top:12px;background-color: #ffffff; padding-left:10px; padding-right:0px; padding-top:10px; }"+
                "ul{padding-left: 10px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:7px;color: #818181;font-size:10px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}"+
                "#factstable td{ width:170px; height:18px;}"+
                ".ext { float:right; }"+
                ".factsdetaildiv{border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom:7px;color:#818181;font-size: 10px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }"+
                "ul .bdr { line-height: 16px;}"+
                "ul{color:#818181;font-size: 10px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }"+
                "ul{list-style-type:none;margin-right: 0px; padding:10px;}"+
                "ul li{padding-bottom:7px; padding-top:10px !important;line-height:10PX; list-style-image:none;font-size:11px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}"+
                "ul{ font-weight:bold;}"+
                "ul p{ padding:0px 10px 0px 0px;line-height: 12px;color: #818181;font-size: 12px;font-family: Arial;}" +
                " li:first-child { margin-top:-38px !important; padding:10px 5px 10px 10px;}"
                ;

      return "<html>" + "<head>" + "<style type=\"text/css\"> " + "@font-face " + "{ " + "font-family: MyCustomFont; " + "src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/" + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.type_face_regular) + "\") " + "}" + "body " + "{ " + "font-family: MyCustomFont; " + "font-size: "+(Utility.isLargeScreen(mContext)? "22px; ": "18px; ") + "color: black" + "}" + htmlString + "</style>" + "</head><body style='margin: 10px'>" + content + "</body></html>";


}
```

My Web View:

```
mDetailsContentsWebView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_product_details_webview_bg));
        mDetailsContentsWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Utility.getInstance(getActivity()).getFormattedWebViewContents(mCurrentProductDetails.mDescription), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        mDetailsContentsWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mDetailsContentsWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mDetailsContentsWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {
                    }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    {
                        event.setLocation(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    }
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Please, somebody let me know if there it's an issue of the HTC phone or my code snippet is wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you check the log cat? That might help in knowing the exact problem.

Comment: WebWiew seems to be not too well designed component. Two things which come to my mind: 1) enable javascript first before loading data 2) use simpler version of load data function: loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding) (I used this one many times and it worked).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at line

```
mDetailsContentsWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Utility.getInstance(getActivity()).getFormattedWebViewContents(mCurrentProductDetails.mDescription), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

You are using "" in the place of baseURL. Try specifying any valid URL or any local file path(from assets).

Or else just replace the line with

```
mDetailsContentsWebView.loadData(Utility.getInstance(getActivity()).getFormattedWebViewContents(mCurrentProductDetails.mDescription), "text/html", "UTF-8");
```